# python pandas cross tab pivot by same category

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I have the following dataframe df:

```
Product | Client_ID | transaction_id | return
A          984574         123             Y
B          984574         123             0
A          365366         234             0
A          467683         356             Y
```

I wanted to create a pivot to see what other products clients buy in the same transaction when they return an item.

So this would be the output for the example above:

```
Product   A     B 
A         0     1
B         0     0
```

I tried this, but get an error:

```
pd.pivot_table(df,index=["return",'Product'],values=["Client_id"],
               columns=["Product"],aggfunc=lambda x: len(x.unique()))

ValueError: Grouper for 'Product' not 1-dimensional
```

Comment: Shouldn't row B col A also be 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
d1 = df.merge(df, on='Client_ID').query('Product_x != Product_y')
pd.crosstab(d1.Product_x, d1.Product_y)

Product_y  A  B
Product_x      
A          0  1
B          1  0
```